# Forming a compound noun

Tags: word-choice, compounds

> I wrote down the bad dream on the written/writing paper.

Which is the correct usage, "written" or "writing" paper in the given sentence?

Comment: I can't quite tell what you're asking, could you please clarify what you want help with?

Comment: @shin: Please do not add back ticks as quotes or emphasis. Use ordinary double quotes, or sometimes bold or italic if needed.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, "writing" isn't even needed. You can just say
"I wrote down the bad dream on the paper" if you were referencing *the* paper in a previous sentence. If this sentence is not paired with another sentence talking about *the paper*, replace "the" with "some".

Answer (score 1):

As @Riley said, `writing` is not necessary in most cases. However if you previously referenced two or more types of paper and wanted to specify which paper you wrote about the dream on, you could say, `I wrote down the bad dream on the writing paper`.

As @Riley also said, if you didn't reference the paper before in your writing, then you would say `some paper`.

Anyway, the correct word is `writing`, the present participle of `to write`, and not the past participle `written`.